# Can't install R package FIRM

Tags: r

I tried to install R packages `FIRM`, but I couldn't.

When I run `devtools::has_devel()`, I get:

> Your system is ready to build packages!

But then when I run this:

```
Sys.setenv(R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS="true")

install_github("mingjingsi/FIRM")

install.packages("/var/folders/vl/d_5p06kj57l85m1zbkkjvffr0000gn/T/RtmpKh4Jry/filee1a07189e395/FIRM_0.1.0.tar.gz",
    type="source",
    repos=NULL,
    dependencies=TRUE)
```

The same error occurs.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0' ld:
> warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
> ld: library not found for -lgfortran clang: error: linker command
> failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [FIRM.so]
> Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘FIRM’
>
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/FIRM’
>   Warning message: In i.p(...) :   installation of package
>   ‘/var/folders/vl/d_5p06kj57l85m1zbkkjvffr0000gn/T//RtmpHZeXAx/file10e6410d4b6b0/FIRM_0.1.0.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

Comment: Perhaps you have not installed developer tools and configure your environment variable to match your (unstated) versions of R and MacOS.

Comment: If you have the most recent version of MacOS you need to install Fortran 8.2.0 from the .dog installer at the tools page.

Comment: Meant to type .dmg